# WebsiteSpark downloads unavailable

Tags: msdn, websitespark

Just got approved for WebsiteSpark, but I can't download from MSDN.  Anybody else have this issue?

*Update:* Currently going through MS support. WebsiteSpark doesn't seem to be talking to MSDN very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stuff is finally available for download.  The issue seemed to be that WebsiteSpark wasn't properly synced with MSDN.  I did have to call [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa948875.aspx) on the issue, and they directed me to a service representative for WebsiteSpark.  I emailed her and a couple of days later I checked that I am able to download.  I didn't get a proper email response from my representative, but I just checked today and the previously unavailable downloads are there.  A total PIA, and I'm not even really sure who fixed my issue.  The only thing I could think that would help others is knowing that they had a similar issue as mine if they describe it to support.  If you go to MSDN [My Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/manage/default.aspx) page and you don't see something like the following, then your MSDN account isn't activated.

[alt text http://img81.imageshack.us/img81/5880/msdnmyaccount.jpg](http://img81.imageshack.us/img81/5880/msdnmyaccount.jpg)